# How to add/remove a button in Jetpack Compose while retaining its size

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, show-hide

I have a button composable, and I want to hide/show it without affecting the surrounding composables' positions. For example, the following code is used to remove/add the button without making the text "Text" go up:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Example(showButton: Boolean) {
    Column {
        Button(
            onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
            modifier = Modifier.alpha(if (showButton) 1f else 0f),
            enabled = showButton
        ) {
            Text(text = "Button")
        }
        Text(text = "Text")
    }
}
```

This code works perfectly, but if I add an infinite animation to the button, my code becomes this:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Example(showButton: Boolean) {
    Column {
        if (showButton) {
            val infiniteTransition = rememberInfiniteTransition()
            val buttonScale by infiniteTransition.animateFloat(
                initialValue = 1f,
                targetValue = 1.005f,
                animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
                    animation = tween(durationMillis = 500, delayMillis = 0, easing = LinearEasing),
                    repeatMode = RepeatMode.Reverse
                )
            )
            Button(
                onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
                modifier = Modifier.graphicsLayer(scaleX = buttonScale, scaleY = buttonScale)
            ) {
                Text(text = "Button")
            }
        } else {
            Button(
                onClick = {},
                modifier = Modifier.alpha(0f),
                enabled = false
            ) {
                Text(text = "Button")
            }
        }
        Text(text = "Text")
    }
}
```

I opted to put `infiniteTransition` and `buttonScale` inside the if statement so the animation will not run if the button is removed, but now I have two buttons composables that I have to keep the same to maintain the same size so as not to affect the position of the surrounding elements (only the text in my example).

My question is: Is there a better way to solve this? I don't think my "solution" is a good practice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control the `showButton` in `Modifer.alpha` as follows. Otherwise, the code will become very repetitive as it grows. You also need to set the `enabled` value for the `Button`. Otherwise, the button will be clickable even if it is not visible. This should also be taken into consideration

```
@Composable
fun Example(showButton: Boolean) {
    Column {
        val infiniteTransition = rememberInfiniteTransition()
        val buttonScale by infiniteTransition.animateFloat(
            initialValue = 1f,
            targetValue = 1.005f,
            animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
                animation = tween(
                    durationMillis = 500,
                    delayMillis = 0,
                    easing = LinearEasing
                ),
                repeatMode = RepeatMode.Reverse
            )
        )

        Button(
            onClick = {},
            modifier = Modifier
                .graphicsLayer(
                    scaleX = if (showButton) buttonScale else 1f,
                    scaleY = if (showButton) buttonScale else 1f
                )
                .alpha(if (showButton) 1f else 0f),
            enabled = showButton

        ) {
            Text(text = "Button")
        }

        Text(text = "Text")
    }
}
```

Comment: But this way the animation runs even when the button is removed.

Comment: Made an edit to stop the animation when the button was removed. Please check